# SIGABRT on any UIView touch

Tags: iphone, uiview, sigabrt

I'm afraid no amount of Googling has been able to save my hyde on this.  I seem to be  getting SIGABRT error anytime I touch the screen of the phone, on any UIView.  The debugger console posts this error before the SIGABRT:

```
.... [310:207] *** -[UIView _exclusiveTouchView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14c0c0
.... [310:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIView _exclusiveTouchView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14c0c0'
```

(this is not my specific call to `_exclusiveTouchView`, of course.)

I would gladly post some code, but the truth is I cannot find (or guess) where this problem may be coming from. This is not happening on any ONE UIView but on all the UIViews in my stack.  I can summarize the display logic, though, perhaps that will shed some light.

So the application is created and a UIWindow is alloc'd.  A single viewcontroller is then alloc'd, which makes and adds its own blank self.view, to which the other UIViews, representing the different game states, are attached.

Interestingly enough, this error is does NOT happen on the Simulator,  but happens consistently on the device.  And I should also mention that the application has yet to override/use any of the touchesBegan:/Ended:/Moved: etc...  In other words, this error happens *without* these methods in the code.

I'm really not understanding where this error is coming from...   Any suggestions?

**EDIT for requested code**  here is a simplified state that still generates SIGABRT on touch:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "WPGame.h"
@class WPGame;
extern WPGame *theGame;

#import "WPGameState.h"

@class IntroView;

@interface IntroStateView : WPGameState {
    NSTimer         *introTimer;
}
+(IntroStateView*)instance;
@end
```

.

```
#import "IntroStateView.h"
#import "StartMenuStateView.h"
static IntroStateView *theOnlyIntro = nil;

@implementation IntroStateView

+(IntroStateView*)instance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!theOnlyIntro) {
            theOnlyIntro = [[IntroStateView alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return theOnlyIntro;
}

- (void)excuseYourself {
    [self changeStateOf:theGame toState:[StartMenuStateView instance]];

}

- (void)startUp {
    [super startUp];

    introTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[theGame introLength]
                            target:self
                                selector:@selector(excuseYourself)
                                userInfo:NULL
                                 repeats:NO];
}

- (void)cleanUp {
    [super cleanUp];
}

- (void)handleEvents:(WPGame*)game {
    [super handleEvents:game];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    theOnlyIntro = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

and if you need to see parts of the WPGameState subclass of UIView, it can be found here to save some post length: http://tinypaste.com/732bb

Comment: Please provide the simplest UIView subclass code that reproduces the issue. We will be able to help from there.

Comment: Not sure if it is directly related but using a singleton view is definitely singleton abuse. Views should be stupid and interchangeable. Each view should only have enough logic to handle its immediate display needs. They should not have critical app logic in them such that only one per app has to exist. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: @TechZen - in terms of design, these are unique views responsible for most of its own environment that represent individual gamestates.  they are meant to have critical logic, but not app logic.  i do agree, though, non-game apps should stay away from singleton views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved -- it seems there was some name clash between the main application's singleton `window` variable, and the gamestate manager's use of the `window` variable, as well.  As TechZen mentioned, *The code is trying to send a UIWindow message to a UIView which does not have the method.*  Here, `window` was used separately by the main application as a UIWindow and `window` was also being used by WPGameState as its viewport, a UIView, causing ambiguity within the frameworks.

Second use of **`window`** has been renamed to **`viewport`**, resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that somewhere you assign a view to a property that should hold a window. The code is trying to send a UIWindow message to a UIView which does not have the method. (UIWindow is a subclass of UIView.)

I don't see the immediate cause but this his app shows severe design problems. You have a UIView subclass of WPGameState which itself has a UIView property called `window`. This breaks the Model-View-Controller design pattern badly.

None of the logic in either `WPGameState` nor `IntroStateView` belong in a view, that logic belongs in a view controller. You should have a single view controller that manages both views and handles their display, timers etc. The views should only know how to draw themselves in response to commands from the view controller.

(And why the explicative-deleted is there a ***singleton*** view? This is the kind of singleton abuse that gets singletons banned from use in some shops.)

Neither should the "game state" be in either a view or a view controller but instead should reside in its own custom data model object.

The kind of problem you are seeing is why MVC is used in the first place. By cramming so much logic into your views, you can set off an unpredictable cascade of errors just by touching the interface. If your design was more modular with clear separation of function, you would know automatically where this problem was coming from.

Comment: @TechZen - ok, i see where you're coming from, though i disagree.  here, i have one view controller running as the display server, while the views (individual and unique gamestates), implemented through singletons, are attached to the display server's self.view, as needed.  this is why the class holds no critical logic, save for device rotation and generalized view management.  in this shop, we respect the MVC approach for certain tasks, but this is not one of them.  however... i will gladly upvote your answer here because it did help me to find the actual bug.

Comment: I won't tell you your business but I would advise that you match your design to the API. I can tell from your terminology that you're coming from a strong C++ (or similar) background and that your trying to map that experience onto this API. Objective-C and the API are flexible enough that you can do whatever you want but if you don't build around a strong MVC design you will be fighting the API all the way instead of letting it help you.

Answer (score 0):

First thoughts: _exclusiveTouchView is a member variable of UIWindow, it appears the device does not have a UIWindow in its view hierarchy, more specifically its responder chain.  Insure that a Window is indeed being allocated and is the top level view of your view hierarchy.    Are you using Interface Builder or rolling your own?

Comment: rolling my own.  the app delegate loads up a singleton class responsible for taking over the entire application.  this is where a UIWindow is declared and alloc'd the following way (window is a class variable with a retain property):
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

from then on, the view controller is loaded, makes its own self.view and attaches THAT to the [window addSubview:(the single VC self.view)]

Comment: Where is UIView *window; set up?  Can you please post your startup code?  The stuff that is usually in - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application...  

What is viewOutlet initialized to?
window = [theGame viewOutlet];

--- TIP -----
In your init code, you call [super init] and then ..initWithFrame (Which also calls [super init].  This is not good, just subclass (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect or don't call [super init] explicitly.

Comment: the UIWindow *window was declared as a class variable in the game singleton header.  it was allocated in the singleton implementation file as described in my comment above.  thanks for the tip on initWithFrame calling super init. i had my doubts about that, but took a chance. (+1)